# DataContext System.NullReferenceException c# xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datacontext

I tried to implement an example from [Msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com) but a null reference exception ocurred and I don't know why:
So here is my C# code of the Mainpage.xaml.cs file:

```
     // Create an instance of the MyColors class 
        // that implements INotifyPropertyChanged.
        MyColors textcolor = new MyColors();

        // Brush1 is set to be a SolidColorBrush with the value Red.
        textcolor.Brush1 = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

        // Set the DataContext of the TextBox MyTextBox.
        MyTextBox.DataContext = textcolor; //HERE THE ERROR OCCURS!

        // Create the binding and associate it with the text box.
        Binding binding = new Binding() { Path = new PropertyPath("Brush1") };
        MyTextBox.SetBinding(TextBox.ForegroundProperty, binding);
```

And here is the xaml code behind:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" Text="Text" Foreground="{Binding Brush1}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Where do you call it? Is it by any chance in `Window`'s constructor ? If yes is it before or after `InitializeComponent`?

Comment: Can you give context for the code? Is it being colled in the constructor? If so, are you calling InitializeComponent() before it? (that's the most obivious pitfall).

Comment: You are right i called it after it, now i get no exception but the foreground doesnt get red @dkozl

Comment: Can you show how `MyColors` looks like? Mainly is `Brush1` a public poprerty?

Comment: @dkozl i found my answer ...its because the foreground only applies if the textblock is loosing focus. If you answer my question as an answer :D I can mark it as the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment if you refer to `MyTextBox` in the `Window`'s consstructor you need to do it after `InitializeComponent()` is called which builds the tree of the XAML

```
InitializeComponent();

MyColors textcolor = new MyColors();
textcolor.Brush1 = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
MyTextBox.DataContext = textcolor;
```